# How to deploy a html and js website to heroku, and what should the procfile be?

Tags: html, heroku, command, procfile

I want to make a basic website to show some people and was thinking of hosting with heroku as its has been pretty good for other things.

However, I wasn't sure what to put in the procfile to just be able to have a html webpage show at https://**appname**.heroku.com. I tried googling it but all I was able to find was node.js stuff, and I don't want to have to get into that. All I really need is the command to put in the procfile.

If you have anything to contribute please add it here, and thank you if you already have.

Comment: Heroku hosting allows you to manage the backend of your website, which is why you have been reading about NodeJS (yet heroku provides other platforms as well). You'll have to provide a server to your project so it can be served to the client. The procfile only tells Heroku which command to execute to start your service. For example, if you go with NodeJS and your server code is in a file called `main.js`, procfile will contain the following: `web: node main.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have in mind if it is a static page, I don't recommend you heroku. Instead upload it to both vercel or github pages because heroku has a limit of deployments and after 30 minutes of inactivity yo get the server sleeping so the next time you open the app, you will late a bit... Moreover, both vercel and github pages have https

By the other hand with vercel you can create an app from a repo, that means that you can to link an app with a repo so each time you make a push, the app in vercel gets deployed automatically (is the method I use)

Comment: Can I host a java program on vercel as well. Because I also want to be able to have a java back end that accepts connections. I will still try vercel for my html and js website though.

Comment: I'm not very sure on this, sorry, but the backend is a good idea to upload to heroku, the frontend is better uploading to vercel